# Having trouble loading custom data from firebase using swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, codable, decodable

I followed the directions on the firebase website and came up with the code below labeled NEW CODE. The error I am getting is:

Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Result' with an argument list of type '(@escaping () throws -> CombinedModel?)'

I have tried researching about the Result object and this error but have not found anything that would help me directly. I was able to read the data using the old way (which I will post below), but am trying to follow Googles documentation 
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

OLD CODE

```
func readData(word: String) -> CombinedModel? {
        print("reading data")
        let docRef = db.collection(K.FBConstants.dictionaryCollectionName).document(word)
        var wordResults: CombinedModel? = nil

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let e = error {
                print("Error loading data: \(e)")
                return
            } else {

                do {
                    if let resultData = try document?.data(as: CombinedModel.self){
                        print("Definitions: \(resultData.definitionsArray)")
                        print("\n Synonyms: \(resultData.synonyms)")
                        wordResults = resultData
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error decoding: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        return wordResults
    }
```

NEW CODE

```
    func newReadData(word: String) -> CombinedModel? {
        let docRef = db.collection(K.FBConstants.dictionaryCollectionName).document(word)

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            let result = Result {
                try document.flatMap {
                    try $0.data(as: CombinedModel.self)
                }
            }
            switch result {
            case .success(let combinedModel):
                if let combinedModel = combinedModel {
                    print("CombinedModel: \(combinedModel)")
                } else {
                    print("Document does not exist")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error decoding city: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the codable custom class I created for reading the data.

```
struct CombinedModel: Codable {
    var definitionsArray: [WordModel]
    var synonyms: [String]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case definitionsArray
        case synonyms
    }
}

struct WordModel: Codable {

    let id: String
    let partOfSpeech: String
    let definitions: [String]
    let example: [String]
    let ipa: String
    let audio: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case partOfSpeech
        case definitions
        case example
        case ipa
        case audio
    }
}

struct ThesaurusModel: Codable {

    var synonyms: [String]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case synonyms
    }
}
```

Comment: What and why are you doing this `let result = Result`? It doesn't serve any purpose in this use case. Why this `-> CombinedModel?` as your function doesn't (and shouldn't) return anything. Can you clarify what you're attempting here? There may be ways to significantly simplify that code.

Comment: I agree there are ways to simplify the code. I was just trying to follow Google's documentation of how they recommend reading custom objects. If you follow this link you can see what I am talking about. This was more for me trying to understand there method of doing it and to better get a graps of the new Result object that swift 5 has.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Understood. To clarify, Firestore does not have custom objects so that code isn't reading a custom object. It's reading a document (a DocumentSnapshot) and casting that documents fields to *your* object (a City object in the documentation). Note that also, the code in the documentation doesn't return anything (because it can't). Just trying to save you some grief!

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the clarification, I'm learning as I go so sometimes I have trouble understanding the code and that really helps. I ended up creating a variable outside the closure, setting it in the closure and then returning it. I think it works correctly(correct me if I'm wrong) but now when I am calling the read function in other functions It appears that the code is executing out of order. I think I need a completion handler which I am reading about now, but if you have any recommendations I would love to hear!

Comment: Firebase is asynchronous so let the Firebase closures control the pacing of the rest of the code. #1 thing is don't attempt to return data from a closure - setting a class level var outside the closure is fine but be sure not to do anything what that var until the closure completes. As you mentioned, you can leverage a completion handler. However, suppose you're populating a tableView dataSource; read the data from Firebase, iterate over it populating the array and then still within the closure, right after the for loop, call tableView.reloadData. Post another question if you get stuck!

Comment: Thank you so much Jay! After reading what you wrote I started to see the bigger picture in the sense of the flow of how the program executes. I did a little more reading based on that and realized my code was not in the right places. I just finished editing everything. I had to move much of my code into the closures which fixed the "things executing out of order" and I also made some protocols and called delegate methods inside the closures. I'm not sure if that made sense without context, but what you said really helped and guided me toward thinking in the right direction, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I realized the issue with the Result object was that Xcode was reading it as a structure that I created in a different file, but once I  changed the name of that structure(it was named Result previously), it recognized the Result object as the correct object which is of type: enum Result where Failure : Error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're getting close - minus the type error. From what I can tell, your error:

`Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Result' with an argument list of type '(@escaping () throws -> CombinedModel?)'`

Refers to this portion of code:

```
let result = Result {
    try document.flatMap {
        try $0.data(as: CombinedModel.self)
    }
}
```

At least, this is the portion of code that looks off to me. Your `(document, error)` variable as a whole represents your result. You shouldn't need a `Result` middleman.

The real focus should be around determining whether or not there is an error. If there isn't you should read the document.

A working approach should look something like this:

```
func newReadData(word: String) -> CombinedModel? {
    let docRef = db.collection(K.FBConstants.dictionaryCollectionName).document(word)

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        guard let fbDoc = document else {
            // document is nil, parse the error object and handle it.
        }

        if let resultData = try fbDoc?.data(as: CombinedModel.self) {
            return resultData
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know how that goes for you! Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely will work and I appreciate the answer. I actually just realized the issue with the Result object was that Xcode reading it as a structure I created but once I  changed the name of that structure, it recognized the Result object as the correct object: enum Result<Success, Failure> where Failure : Error